# Lambda output layer

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras

I've a sequential model as follows with a linear activation function (Keras default) for the single output neuron:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add( ...
...
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

I need the final number to be bounded by 100, so I modified the last line of code above to be:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x%100, output_shape=(1)))
```

- Is it correct? Does x here means the net as I expect ?
- I get an error: "In Lambda, `output_shape` must be a list, a tuple, or a function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output_shape=(1)` should be `output_shape=(1,)`.

BTW, I consider following alternatives being better:

- Clip output to `[0.0, 100.0]`.

  ```
  #...
  model.add(Dense(1)) #-2nd line from code in question
  model.add(Lambda(lambda x: max(0., min(x,100.)), output_shape=(1,)))
  ```

This is a continuous function as opposed to mod 100.

- Use scaled sigmoid output layer.

  ```
  #...
  model.add(Dense(1), activation='sigmoid')
  model.add(Lambda(lambda x:x*100., output_shape=(1,)))
  ```

This is differentiable, being friendly to SGD.

Comment: Thank you so much, but doesn't this mean I will have 100 output neurons not a single one ?

Comment: @hesham-eraqi No, I meant make final `dense` layer output value in `[0.0, 1.0]` with sigmoid activation, then use lambda to scale to `[0.0, 100.0]`.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good workaround. But I I only wanted to use a single direct layer of lamda, does that line of code will have 100 output neurons not a single one ?